# Image Extension include all parameters url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all the images that have the extension .svg. This works, but the problem is images that have parameters in the URL get ignored.

I am thinking some kind of wild card like svg?/* ? But I cannot figure it out ?

Thanks

```
 // SVG images
        (function() {
            svgImages = function() {
                $('img[src$=".svg?/*"]').each(function() {
                    var $img = $(this);
                    var $imgID = $img.attr('id');
                    var $imgClass = $img.attr('class');
                    var $imgData = $(this).data();
                    var $imgAlt = $img.attr('alt');
                    var $imgURL = $img.attr('src');
                    $.get($imgURL, function(data) {
                        var $svg = $(data).find('svg');
                        if (typeof $imgID !== 'undefined') {
                            $svg = $svg.attr('id', $imgID);
                        }
                        if (typeof $imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                            $svg = $svg.attr('class', $imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
                        }
                        if (typeof $imgAlt !== 'undefined') {
                            $svg = $svg.attr('aria-label', $imgAlt);
                        }
                        // Add replaced image data attributes to the new SVG
                        $.each($imgData, function(key, value) {
                            $svg = $svg.attr('data-' + key, value);
                        });
                        // Check if the viewport is set, if the viewport is not set the SVG wont't scale.
                        if (!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                            $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'));
                        }
                        $svg = $svg.attr('role', 'img');
                        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
                        // Replace image with new SVG
                        $img.replaceWith($svg);
                    }, 'xml');
                });
            };
            if ($('img[src$=".svg"]').length) {
                svgImages();
            }
        }());
```

For example this URL doesn't pick up that it's a SVG

-/media/images/logo/test.svg?&hash=5E5E5D597365C12424C3E7865285E596B3F8BEF0

Comment: Can you try `.svg?*` ? Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the **[attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)** selector `[src*=".svg"]`.

When using a `$` you are saying that you want the `src` to **[end with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)** `.svg` which won't work in your case.

```js
$('img[src*=".svg"]').each((i, item) => { console.log(item) })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="abc.svg">
<img src="abc.jpg">
<img src="123.svg">
<img src="abc.png">
<img src="-/media/images/logo/test.svg?&hash=5E5E5D597365C12424C3E7865285E596B3F8BEF0">
```

Comment: Indeed this is the right answer. My comment above for `.svg?*` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed right answer is already provided, the $('img[src*=".svg"]') '$' checks for ends with.
Another way can also me implemented by getting the src value and check if it contains ".svg"

```
    if($('img').prop('src').contains('.svg')).each(idx,item)
    {
    $(item) // use this object 
    }
```